# how to insert data inside Pattern-start/Pattern-end with sed or awk?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a yaml file file that has `ssl_ruleN` where N is a number from 1 to 100.
I want to add in each rule `local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_ruleN` , so i need to match each rule in a for.
Tried with sed, but the problem is apparently it matches rule10 and rule1 as well. In this way, it ended up rule2 contains data from rule20 as well.

and input file:

```
ssl_rule.ssl_rule1: {action: block, dst_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection1',
  dst_services: 'local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL', dst_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted',
  name: ssl_rule1, rid: 1, src_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection1',
  src_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted'}
ssl_rule.ssl_rule10: {action: block, dst_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection10',
  dst_services: 'local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL', dst_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted',
  name: ssl_rule10, rid: 10, src_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection10',
  src_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted'}
ssl_rule.ssl_rule11: {action: block, dst_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection11',
  dst_services: 'local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL', dst_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted',
  name: ssl_rule11, rid: 11, src_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection11',
  src_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted'}
ssl_rule.ssl_rule12: {action: block_with_reset, dst_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection12',
  dst_services: 'local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL', dst_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted',
  name: ssl_rule12, rid: 12, src_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection12',
  src_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted'}
ssl_rule.ssl_rule25:
  action: decrypt_resign
  decryption_certs: ['local:internal_ca_certificate.Internal_Cert_4096']
  dst_networks: local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection25
  dst_services: local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL
  dst_zones: local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted
  name: ssl_rule25
  rid: 25
  src_networks: local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection25
  src_zones: local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted
```

What I tried:

```
for i in `seq 1 53`;do 
    sed  "/ssl_rule.ssl_rule${i}[:] /,/action:/{s/action:/cipher_suites: \'local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_rule$i\', action:/g;}" -i  cucu.yaml
done
```

But it somehow mixes the rules up, rule10 containing rule1 and so on. Note that I used /start/,/end/ pattern because technique because sometimes the rules span several lines, and i want to match them as well ( example rule25 )

Expected output ( each rule to contain `local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_ruleN` inside, `N` corresponding with the `ruleN` )

```
ssl_rule.ssl_rule1: {local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_rule1, action: block, dst_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection1',
  dst_services: 'local:rule_ports_fragment.PortSelectionSSL', dst_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted',
  name: ssl_rule1, rid: 1, src_networks: 'local:rule_networks_fragment.RoutedNetGrpSelection1',
  src_zones: 'local:rule_zones_fragment.ZoneSelectionRouted'}
```

Comment: Can you share the input file and a proper expected output? With the current information it is not clear

Comment: `/ssl_rule1: {/` does not match `ssl_rule10: {`. Your problem is that your command looks for the next line which matches `/action:/` and prints every line in between, where apparently the ending condition is met on the line which coincidentally also contains `ssl_rule10`. We can guess that you want to remove the `,/action:/` part or maybe explain what you *do* want to match which caused you to put in that condition in the first place.

Comment: You're right @tripleee! That is weird, i thought it will match only between the patterns, but i guess it needs to be on another line. I want to insert stuff inside the {} for each rule, right before action, something like: `"/ssl_rule.ssl_rule${i}\: /,/action:/{s/action:/cipher_suites: \'local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_rule$i\', action:/g;}" `. I'm using the pattern start and end style because some of these are not on the same line.

Comment: That `${i}` looks suspicious. You should probably change it to a regular expression which matches all the lines you want to change (and no others) and do a single `sed` pass over the whole file. You can use a backreference to capture the number so you can use in the replacement string.

Comment: Also, escaping the colon after it with a backslash isn't necessary or useful.

Comment: And the `/g` flag is probably misplaced (but harmless) unless you specifically expect multiple `action:` matches on a single line, and really intend to replace all of them.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry I didn't think about that. Re-formulated the question. You are right about /g, it partially solves the question if i remove it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in comments, you apparently don't actually want `sed` to modify from the line matching `ssl_rule` through the next line matching `action:`

Additionally, looping over a file multiple times and doing a single substitution on each pass is extremely inefficient and inelegant. In most situations, you should tell `sed` what you want to do to the entire file.

To match the next `action:` line immediately after one of the matching rules, I would switch to Awk, which makes this sort of thing very easy.

```
awk '/^ssl_rule\.ssl_rule/ { r = 0 + substr($1, 18); n = (r >= 1 && r <= 53) }
   n && /action:/ { sub(/action:/, "cipher_suites: \047local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_rule" r "\047, action:/"); n = 0} 1'  cucu.yaml >cucu.tmp &&
mv cucu.tmp cucu.yaml
```

Returning to a `sed` answer, just to tie together some loose ends.

The regular expression `\([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]\|5[0-3\)` matches the numbers 1 through 53.  The parentheses conveniently also capture the matching number so we can refer back to it with `\1` in the replacement string.

```
sed -i '/ssl_rule\.ssl_rule\([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]\|5[0-3\): /s/action:/cipher_suites: '"'"'local:cipher_suites.cipher_suites_rule\1'"'"', action:/' -i  cucu.yaml
```

I switched to single quotes around this script, which then requires the literal single quotes to be expressed with a slightly odd `'"'"'` sequence which closes the current single-quoted expression, adds a literal single quote (quoted with double quotes to escape it from the shell) and opens a new single-quoted expression, all adjacent to each other.

There is no need to backslash-escape a colon, but the dot should be escaped to match it literally (an unescaped dot matches any character).

Comment: awk gives me: "^ syntax error" pointin the ``;`` after ``action/"``; Any ideea why ?

Comment: There was a missing ``)``  right before ``;`` after ``action/"``;  Thanks @tripleee !

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for the fix (and the accept)!